# Loop through children and display each, as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

How do I loop through all of my children, and display each? I would like to know the best
way to do this.

**my children and container**
five children, one plays every sec, 1,2,3, etc.

```
 var square1:Square1 = new Square1;
 var square2:Square2 = new Square2;
 var square3:Square3 = new Square3;
 var square4:Square4 = new Square4;
 var square5:Square5 = new Square5;

 var container:Sprite = new Sprite;
 addChild(container);
 container.addChild(square1)
 container.addChild(square2)
 container.addChild(square3)
 container.addChild(square4)
 container.addChild(square5)
```

**my timer**

```
 var timly:Timer = new Timer(1000, 5);   
  timly.start();
  timly.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onLoop);
```

Note:
Tried for loop, numChildren -1, and visibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea...

Set the squares to `square#.visible = false` and put them in an array `mySquaresArray`.

Then...

```
function onLoop( e:Event )
{
    curCount = e.target.currentCount;

    if( curCount > 1 ) {
        var previous_square = curCount -2;
        mySquaresArray[previous_square].visible = false;
    }

    var current_square = curCount - 1;
    mySquaresArray[current_square].visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Great idea. See what I got before I close this one. I put the children in an array, but it's not working.